# Sort Issue on Databound Grid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My DatagridView is bound to a datatable, after binding my datagridview to datatable, I am adding a new row to my datatable at 0 index, this row will serve as GrandTotals row, this row is frozen, this is working fine except when user click on one of column headers to sort the grid, my top grand totals row gets sorted and another row appears as grand totals row as a result of sort operation, I discovered that when grid is binded to a datatable, I cannot access the sortcompare event of grid, I also tried to make a copy of my top row when user click on column header so I can add it back in Sorted event (this event is firing up) but ColumnHeaderMouseClick event is not firing up.

Any advice on the situation, my goal is to keep my grand totals row on the top.